# Java8 Issue With JAXB Marshaller Header

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a library created which uses jaxb to marshal/unmarshal an xml payload related to web service calls (no json). These calls work perfectly in my library. Once I pull it into a larger project, the calls to setProperty() fail with the following exception.

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders value: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

anyone have any ideas what is going on here? My searches have all come up as wild goose chases. Here's the method in question:

```
public String serializeXML() throws JAXBException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MPICRequest.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<!DOCTYPE xgdquery SYSTEM \"xgdquery.dtd\">");
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    marshaller.marshal(this, byteStream);
    return new String(byteStream.toByteArray());
}
```

## xmlHeaders

I've seen both 'com.sun.xml.internal.bin.xmlHeaders' and 'com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders' in various document and blogs. Both options throw an exception, but each in a different project.

com.sun.xml.internal.. throws an exception in my consuming jar when method executed as larger problem space:

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders value: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

com.sun.xml.. throws an exception in my library jar when method executed in isolation:

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders value: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

## JAXB Libraries

The JAXBContext differs between the two jars during run time. I've tried to force the JAXB library via maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

In the case of the consuming project here's the JAXBContext:

```
jar:file:/private/tmp/hadoop-usr/nm-local-dir/usercache/usr/appcache/application_1502287345977_0001/filecache/10/porter-samza-0.4.14-dist.tar.gz/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.class Build-Id: 2.2.3
```

In the case of my reusable library the context is (completely ignoring my jaxb-api:2.2.3 dependency):

jar:file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar!/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.class Build-Id: 1.8.0_121

Comment: What java version does the "larger project" use at runtime?

Comment: jaxb library issue maybe?

Comment: When I search the [source code](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2) of the JDK's JAXB implementation, I find a constant named `com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders`, but not one named `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders`. Try using the name without `internal` in it.

Comment: Both projects us java8

Comment: I have edited the question to address the comments above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a bad maven dependency on my part. There are two jaxb related dependencies that looked correct, jaxb-api and jaxb-impl. The jaxb-impl fixed my problem

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```